# How do I use the forall loop to check if all rows have the same number of columns in a Vector in Scala?

Tags: scala, loops, vector, forall

So I have a generic vector: 1:`vec: Vector[Vector[T]]`
Now I wanna use the **require** and **forall** to check if the length of each row is the same.
This is how far I've gotten:
2:`require(vec.forall(row => data(row).length == ???)`
So essentially I wanna make sure that each row has same number of columns, I don't wanna use 3:`data(row + 1).length` since I could probably use a for loop in that case. Can anyone give a tip on how to resolve code 2?

Comment: Get the length of head and compare it against foreach of tail? (Don't forget to handle empty collection).

Comment: My lord a stackoverflow question that doesn't get completely demolished... What a twist!

Answer (score 2):

If all the rows must have the same length, you can compare each row with any of the others.

```scala
if (vec.size < 2) true  // vacuous
else {
  val firstLength = data(vec.head).length
  vec.forall(row => data(row).length == firstLength)
}
```

Strictly speaking, the first comparison in the `forall` will always be true, but `Vector.tail` is probably more work than performing the comparison; if `data(row).length` is particularly expensive, making it

```scala
vec.tail.forall(...)
```

might be worth it.

(If instead of a `Vector`, we were dealing with a `List`, `tail` is most definitely cheaper than `data(row).length`, though other cautions around using `List` may apply)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 3x4 vector of vectors such as for instance

```
val xs = Vector.tabulate(3) { _ => Vector.tabulate(4) { _ =>  1 }}
```

namely,

```
Vector(Vector(1, 1, 1, 1), 
       Vector(1, 1, 1, 1), 
       Vector(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Collect the size for each nested vector,

```
val s = xs.map {_.size}
// Vector(4, 4, 4)
```

Now we can compare consecutive sizes with `Vector.forall` by pairing them with

```
s.zip(s.drop(1))
// Vector((4,4), (4,4))
```

where the first pair corresponds to the first and second vector sizes, and the second pair to the second and third vector sizes; thus

```
s.zip(s.drop(1)).forall { case(a,b) => a == b }
// true
```

With this approach we can define other predicates in `Vector.forall`, such as monotonically increasing pairs,

```
val xs = Vector(Vector(1), Vector(1,2), Vector(1,2,3))

val s = xs.map {_.size}
// Vector(1, 2, 3)

s.zip(s.drop(1))
// Vector((1,2), (2,3))

s.zip(s.drop(1)).forall { case(a,b) => a == b }
// false

s.zip(s.drop(1)).forall { case(a,b) => a < b }
// true
```